# How do I select the number of distinct days in a date range?

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to use the T-SQL function `DATEDIFF` to select the number of distinct dates in a time period.

The following query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-01-01 01:23:45', '2012-01-02 01:23:45')
```

selects `1`, which is one less than I want. There are two distinct dates in the range: 2012-01-01 and 2012-01-02.

It is not correct to add one to the result in the general case. The following query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-01-02 00:00:00')
```

selects `1`, which is correct, because there is only one distinct date in the range.

I'm sure there is a simple bit of arithmetic that I'm missing to calculate this. Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you think the second query shouldn't return `1`. You need to clarify the manner in which the time element is desired to affect to the outcome.

Comment: @Thomas - I think you misread me. The second query does and should return `1`. The first query returns `1`, but I want it to return `2`.

Comment: Why should the first one return 2? What about this scenario: `DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-01-02 00:00:01')`. Is it that you want the number of 24 hour periods between the two datetime values?

Comment: How exactly are you defining "distinct days"? DateDiff defines it by only looking at the date element in the two datetime values. Given your post, you clearly have an alternate definition. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-01-01 01:23:45', '2012-01-02 01:23:45')
```

Given this example, it should still be `1`, because there is only one day that has passed.  Even if you are considering the **start** of a day, it would still be only one (as this range includes the start of only `2012-01-02 00:00:00`).

Your logic for:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-01-01 01:23:45', '2012-01-02 01:23:45')
```

and

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-01-02 00:00:00')
```

Should be the same, as mathematically they are the same range.  `DATEDIFF` compares based on the granularity of the first paramter.  You are comparing by `day`, so SQL Server will see `2012-01-01` to `2012-01-02` as a `1` day difference.

An extremely ugly (and in my opinion, bad) workaround would be something like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, yourStartDate, dateadd(ss, -1, yourEndDate)) + 1
```

What this would do is handle inclusive dates.  So you could basically have this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-01-01 01:23:45', dateadd(ss, -1, '2012-01-02 01:23:45')) + 1
```

Would equal `2` and this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', dateadd(ss, -1, '2012-01-02 00:00:00')) + 1
```

Would equal `1`.  I don't think this is the best idea in the world, but it will give you your desired output.  It all boils down to business logic.

Comment: I realise that SQL Server is acting consistently when I use the `DATEDIFF` function. Maybe I need to use a different function. How do I get SQL Server to count the number of distinct date values in the range? In my first example, the distinct date values are 2012-01-01 and 2012-01-02. In my second example, the distinct date value is 2012-01-01.